# Why do we prefer not to specify the constant factor in Big-O notation?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, constants, complexity-theory

Let's consider classic big O notation definition ([proof link](http://www.phil.uu.nl/datastructuren/10-11/knuth_big_omicron.pdf)):

> `O(f(n))` is the set of all functions such that there exist positive constants `C` and `n0` with  `|g(n)| ≤ C * f(n)`, for all `n ≥ n_0`.

According to this definition it is legal to do the following (`g1` and `g2` are the functions that describe two algorithms complexity):

```
g1(n) = 9999 * n^2 + n ∈ O(9999 * n^2)

g2(n) = 5 * n^2 + N ∈ O(5 * n^2)
```

And it is also legal to note functions as:

```
g1(n) = 9999 * N^2 + N ∈ O(n^2)

g2(n) = 5 * N^2 + N ∈ O(n^2)
```

As you can see the first variant `O(9999*N^2)` vs `(5*N^2)` is much more precise and gives us clear vision which algorithm is faster. The second one does not show us anything.

The question is: why nobody use the first variant?

Comment: It's more about what you can expect from the function if you increase the amount of items (n=1 vs n=1,000 vs n=1,000,000). If you would plot the function, you would clearly classify it as a parabola (geometric figure). The `n` doesn't change much to that, and neither does the `9999`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of the `O()` notation is, from the get go, the opposite of noting something "precisely". The very idea is to mask "precise" differences between algorithms, as well as being able to ignore the effect of computing hardware specifics and the choice of compiler or programming language. Indeed, `g_1(n)` and `g_2(n)` are both in the same **class** (or set) of functions of `n` - the class `O(n^2)`.  They differ in specifics, but they are similar enough.

The fact that it's a class is why I edited your question and corrected the notation from `= O(9999 * N^2)` to `∈ O(9999 * N^2)`.

By the way - I believe your question would have been a better fit on [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You said: ` opposite of noting something "precisely"` Does it mean that the main goal of using Big O in complexity analysis is just to determine the classes of functions and that's it?

Comment: @NoNameQA: Yes. With `O()` analysis, you want to capture the qualitative dependency on the parameter rather than the specifics.

Comment: Could you provide some proof link about this statement (book will be better): `you want to capture the qualitative dependency on the parameter rather than the specifics`?

Comment: BTW about your correction of my question. I use `=` sign, because of proof link in my original question. Yes, Big O is a set, and yes `∈` is a brilliant sign. But for now we should use (unfortunately) `=` sign.

Comment: And a last one question. I still don't understand real purpose of omitting constants. Yeah it's no problem if we have, say `2N` vs `3N`. But in reality, if we have `9999N` vs `2N` why not to specify constants? It will give us really clear vision that  second algorithm tremendously better.  It will cost nothing to guy who will evaluate complexity.

Comment: @NoNameQA: Well, let me ask you this: When does 9999N signfiy? That is, what are the units in which `g1(n)` is given?

Comment: That's a great question, because any constant has it own weight (like different operator: +, -,&, /; `if` and `return` statements; etc) so if we just specify `9999N` we have no idea what weight has this `9999` constant. But if algorithms do the same thing, then in 99% they have very similar weight. Also, we could specify it explicitly like we do, when we evaluate sort algorithm (counting number of swaps and `if` statements). So, I believe that `9999N` vs `3N` in 99.9% cases will have very similar meaning in terms of constant weights.

Comment: But this is not the point. By definition, the order notation is **independent** of constants.